# How to export DatagridView to Excel

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with a button that exports the data within the datagridview to an excel workbook.

I have gotten it to work but it doesn't add the data. only the headers of each column. Also I am not sure how to tell it to ignore the ID column.

I have looked over this code like 100  times and i cannot find the fault

UPDATE: It seems to work when i enter a few rows of data but it ignores the first row of data in the datagridview.

Code:

```
Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
PictureBox2.Click
    ExportToExcel()
End Sub

Private Sub ExportToExcel()
    ' Creating a Excel object.
    Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    Dim workbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
    Dim worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet = Nothing

    Try

        worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet

        worksheet.Name = "ExportedFromDatGrid"

        Dim cellRowIndex As Integer = 1
        Dim cellColumnIndex As Integer = 1

        'Loop through each row and read value from each column.
        For i As Integer = 0 To FleetDataGridView.Rows.Count - 2
            For j As Integer = 0 To FleetDataGridView.Columns.Count - 1
                ' Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check.
                If cellRowIndex = 1 Then
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = FleetDataGridView.Columns(j).HeaderText
                Else
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = FleetDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()
                End If
                cellColumnIndex += 1
            Next
            cellColumnIndex = 1
            cellRowIndex += 1
        Next

        'Getting the location and file name of the excel to save from user.
        Dim saveDialog As New SaveFileDialog()
        saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        saveDialog.FilterIndex = 2

        If saveDialog.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName)
            MessageBox.Show("Export Successful")
        End If
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        excel.Quit()
        workbook = Nothing
        excel = Nothing
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know your code is **not** in C#? How is this related to C#?

Comment: my lecturer told me this was C # within visual studio? or is this VB.net?

Comment: If i made a mistake i will change the question immediately sir. sorry @SirRufo

Comment: just remove the c# tag and mark it VB instead

Comment: like that sir @Adam

Comment: yep that works, thanks!

Comment: While working on the first row you only set the header and not the data

Comment: I understand sir but i am not sure how to fix it. @SirRufo

Comment: i run my application. enter the first row of data, check it. then run the export and it only takes the headers and not the first row of data. But if i enter 2 rows of data. it takes the 2nd row of data in the export.

Comment: I know, I see your code

Comment: Can you see the error in my code sir? @SirRufo

Comment: I described the failure in a comment 5min ago

Comment: Thanks for asking this question and leaving it up. Helped me in my project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the headers in a separate loop

```
    Dim cellRowIndex As Integer = 1
    Dim cellColumnIndex As Integer = 1

    'Write headers
    For j As Integer = 0 To FleetDataGridView.Columns.Count - 1
        worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = FleetDataGridView.Columns(j).HeaderText
        cellColumnIndex += 1
    Next
    cellColumnIndex = 1
    cellRowIndex += 1

    'Loop through each row and read value from each column.
    For i As Integer = 0 To FleetDataGridView.Rows.Count - 2
        For j As Integer = 0 To FleetDataGridView.Columns.Count - 1
            ' Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check.
            worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = FleetDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()
            cellColumnIndex += 1
        Next
        cellColumnIndex = 1
        cellRowIndex += 1
    Next
```

Comment: that worked! Thank you so much sir! i cant mark as answer yet it says to wait 5mins. If i may ask sir. How would i tell it to ignore the ID column? like it must not put that in the spreadsheet